# Use a double integral in polar coordinates to find the area

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

[image]

So the area is just an intersection of two circles

Converting the two circles to polar coordinates, I get:

1. $r(r-2\sin\theta)=0$, and
2. $r(r-2\cos\theta)=0$

Ummm so $r =0$ and r = $2\sin\theta$ and r=$2\cos\theta$ ? are those the boundaries?

Comment: find the intersection points in $x,y$ plane then by using $x=rcos(\theta)..$ you will find $r,\theta..$ then you can find the boundries..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you advance.

> $$ \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{2\sin \theta}rdrd\theta + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{2\cos \theta}  rdrd\theta. $$

**Note:** To find the point of intersection of both circles solve the two equations

1)

> $$ r=2\sin \theta,\quad  r=2\cos \theta. $$

2)

> $$ \iint_D dxdy = \iint_D r dr d\theta.  $$

Comment: Why is the second boundary from pi/4 to pi/2?

Comment: Also is the integrand just 'r'?

Comment: @Rob: Plot the region and you will see that the $r$ is bounded by two different curves from the top.

Comment: Is the integrand just 'r'?

Comment: @Rob : the area is given by $$ A=\iint_{D} dx dy $$ and when you change to polar coordinates you need to use the relation $dxdy=rdr d\theta$. Check the Jacobian.